# Подзапрос в Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq2sql

БД: MS SQL Server Express 2017
Бэкенд: Asp net mvc

Каким образом можно переписать на Linq запрос sql такого плана:

```
select a.Num1,
       max(b.ID) as 'ID',
       ( select d.Status 
         from r2 d 
         where d.ID=max(b.ID)) as 'St' 
from r1 a,
     r2 b 
where a.ID=b.InID 
  and a.tstid=1 
group by a.Num1
```

Набросал такой linq запрос:

```
var wer= (from d1 in db.t1 join d2 in db.t2 on d1.ID equals d2.InID where d1.tstid==1
                                  group d2 by d1.Num1 into r
                                  select new ClassName {                                          
                                      Nmr = r.Key,
                                      IdIn = r.Max(d=>d.ID)}
                                  );
```

Но как реализовать подзапрос
`(select d.Status from r2 d where d.ID=max(b.ID))`,чтобы по максимальному ID нашелся статус, не пойму.

Структура.

```
public class R1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int TSTID { get; set; }
        public virtual TST TST { get; set; }
        public int SID { get; set; }
        public virtual S S { get; set; }
        public int Num1{ get; set; }       

        public virtual ICollection<R2> R2{ get; set; }
    }


public class R2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int INID { get; set; }
    public virtual IN IN { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }

    public decimal Values { get; set; }
    public Boolean Status { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Сервер БД-то хоть какой? вдруг он оконные функции знает...

Comment: БД - ms sql server 2017 express

Comment: `SELECT a.Num1, MAX(b.ID) as 'ID', MAX(FIRST_VALUE(b.Status) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Num1 ORDER BY b.ID DESC)) AS Status`, а подзапрос выбросить.

Comment: Так я же просил не как sql видоизменить, а как тоже самое сделать с помощью LInq запроса...

Comment: Приведите код классов сущностей

Comment: Добавил классы в описание

Comment: Рекомендую использовать навигационные свойства, тогда код будет несколько проще (не нужен будет Join)

Comment: Можете пожалуйста привести пример. как это сделать

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.2.php